# CBD Prescribed Cannabis Oil onboard a flight to United Kingdom

Tags: uk, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, south-africa

I will be flying from South Africa to the United Kingdom and was wondering if I will be allowed to take my prescribed CBD oil onboard the flight. Or will I have problems on arrival in London?

Comment: Products labelled CBD are on sale in my local pharmacy in England but I do not know the exact regulations I am afraid.

Comment: I found the official documentation on what can be carried https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions/essential-medicines-and-medical-equipment. But no information on Cannabis anywhere which is sad. It just says prescribed medicines can be carried in excess of 100ml too.

Comment: I would go with the old rules, do not transport cannabis in any form across any border. Not sure about current laws on medicational exceptions.

Comment: You can buy CBD products pretty much everywhere in Europe these days without prescription, even in Boots (https://www.boots.com/wellness/cannabidiol-cbd-oil/love-hemp-cbd-oil-peppermint-600mg-30m-10288905), which is a popular chain in UK and Ireland ... What determines if it is illegal is the content of THC and regulation can be different in SA. Your best option is probably to just buy it when you are in UK.